# Finding the probability two trains are moving simultaneously

Tags: probability, independence, uniform-distribution

Two trains are leaving their station, train $X$ does $A\rightarrow B$ and train $Y$ does $B\rightarrow A$.  each train leaves at an uniformley distributed time between $12:00$ and $12:30$, independently from each other.

Each train drives for 10 minutes untill arriving at their destination.

What is the probability that there exists a moment where both trains are moving simultaneously?

I've denoted $X$ to be the time train $X$ leaves it's station, and the same for $Y$.

We're looking for a moment $t\in [0,30]$ such that $Y\leq t\leq Y+10$ and $X\leq t\leq X+10$.

In other words, $P(|X-Y|<10)$
Since leaving times are independent, we can exchange this for $P(X-10<Y<X)\cdot P(Y-10<X<Y)$

I'm uncertain on how to progress from here, one of my uncertainties is weather or not I can replace $P(X-10<Y<X)$ for $P(X-10<Y)\cdot P(Y<X)$ and vice versa.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that can best be solved by drawing a picture.  The joint departure times just make a square...figure out what part of the square is "good".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the area of the blue coloured region below.

That is $30\times 30 - 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot 20\cdot 20 = 500$ . i.e. (The area of the whole square minus the area of the two triangles in the bottom right and top left)

So the required probability is $\frac{500}{900}=\frac{5}{9}$

[image]

To put it more rigourously . You want $P(|X-Y|<10)$ when $X$ , $Y$ $\sim Unif[0,30]$ and are independent.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

One thing that baffles me- we're doing an 'integral' type of operation on discrete R.V's, does this has any specific meaning about the R.V's?

Comment: No rv is discrete here. X and Y are both continuous random variables. In reality what's going on behind the figures is that you are integrating the uniform density . That is $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{900}\,,(x,y)\in[0,30]\times[0,30]$ over the region $\{|x-y|<10\}$ .

Comment: But sometimes, instead of actually integrating by calculus rules. It is easier to just see geometrically what the area is. In this case, we can just substract the area of both the triangles. Indeed , if you were to integrate by usual rules, then you'll have to take care of the limits of integration and it'll perhaps involve more unnecessary work.

Comment: But just as an aside, when you'll learn measure theory, you'll learn that a Summation is actually an integral(wrt counting measure) and you can indeed talk of integrals in the most general way regardless of whehter the rv is discrete or continuous or neither(there are such things called singular rv's) .

Comment: Incredible intuition, I can only aspire to achieve such vision.

Thank you for your explanation, it is indeed eye opening!